# Trying to write a Morse code translator

Tags: java, algorithm

```
import java.util.*;
class Test1{
static int b=0;
static int c=0;
static boolean convert(HashMap h,String l,int len){
//System.out.println(len);
//if(l.substring(0,len+1)
if(len==0)
return true;
for(int i=2;i<=len;i++){
if(h.get(l.substring(0,i))!=null&&(convert(h,l.substring(i,len+1),len-i))){
//System.out.println(h.get(l.substring(0,i)));
//convert(h,l.substring(i,len+1),len-i);

//System.out.println(l.substring(i,len+1));
System.out.print(h.get(l.substring(0,i)));
}
//else if(l.length=len)
//convert(h,l.substring(i-1,len+1));
}
return true;
}


public static void main(String args[]){
HashMap<String,String> h=new HashMap<String,String>();
h.put(".-","a");
h.put("-...","b");
h.put("-.-.","c");
h.put("-..","d");
h.put("-.","n");
h.put(".---","j");
h.put("---","o");
h.put("--","m");
h.put("-..-","x");
h.put("--.","g");
String l="-..-----.";
int len=l.length();
//Output should be njg, dog, xmg xon,naon
convert(h,l,len-1);
}
}
```

I am stuck on this I need to covert these symbols to a english aplhabets. So if I input string l="-..-----."; output should be **njg, dog, xmg xon,naon**.
I tried to write convert function but I am not able to solve it. Please help

Comment: What kind of error do you get ?

Comment: Could you explain the desired output

Comment: I am not getting any error its like I am not getting desired output. Desired output is all the combination that can be formed with the symbols provided. For example if input given is "-..-----." then desired output will be four words  njg, dog, xmg xon,naon because n stands for -. and so on

Comment: Then what output DO you get? Also, am I correct in that this program is supposed to show all possible interpretations for Morse code where the spaces have been removed?

Comment: This code sample doesn't compile because of this line `if(l.substring(0,len+1)`. Please post a valid code sample. By the way, avoid `static` variables if you don't really need them `static`.

Comment: You're trying to write a Morse converter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method will do the trick

```
static void findTranslation(Map<String, String> map, String message, String translation) {
    if (message != null && !message.isEmpty()) {
        for (String key : map.keySet()) {
            if (message.startsWith(key)) {
                String currentTranslation = translation + map.get(key);
                String restOfTheMessage = message.substring(key.length());
                if (!restOfTheMessage.isEmpty()) {
                    findTranslation(map, restOfTheMessage, currentTranslation);
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println(currentTranslation);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and in your main:

```
String l="-..-----.";
findTranslation(h, l, "");
```

will print:

```
dt9
dttttn
dttt.z
dttmn
dtmtn
dtm.z
dton
dmttn
dmt.z
dmmn
dotn
do.z
x9
xtttn
xtt.z
xtmn
xmtn
xm.z
xon
tit9
tittttn
tittt.z
tittmn
titmtn
titm.z
titon
timttn
timt.z
timmn
tiotn
tio.z
t2tn
t2.z
tu9
tutttn
tutt.z
tutmn
tumtn
tum.z
tuon
nwttn
nwt.z
nwmn
njtn
nj.z
n1n
na9
natttn
natt.z
natmn
namtn
nam.z
naon
```

Comment: Thnku so much it works.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that my speculation in a comment above is correct and that this is supposed to generate all possible interpretations of a Morse code string where the spaces are missing.

A general algorithm would work something like this:

```
List<String> interpret(String input, int symbolStart, String currentInterpretation) {
    list = new List<String>

    if symbolStart >= input.length
        list.add(currentInterpretation)
        return list;
    end if

    for symbolEnd = symbolStart to input.length - 1
        symbol = input between characters symbolStart and symbolEnd (inclusive)
        if symbol is a valid morse letter:
            letter = the letter that symbol represents
            list.addAll( interpret(input, symbolEnd + 1, currentInterpretation + letter ) );
        end if
    end for

    return list;
}

interpret(input, 0, "");
```

This is a recursive solution where the algorithm branches at each possible interpretation, then combines the results of all branches into a single list.